# Use oene physical monitor as two

Tags: xorg, awesome-wm

I have a Big monitor which I would like to simulate more than one monitor.

i.e:

```
------------
|          |
|    M1    |
------------
```

should be treated as:

```
   -------------
   |  M1 |  M2 |
   |     |     |
   -------------
```

I'm running AwesomeWM version 3.5.9 on X11 1.18.3. I don't care if I can achieve this behaviour by changing the settings of my window manager or the xserver. Whichever way is the easiest.

Cheers

Comment: Does changing the awesome version count? The unreleased git/master version of awesome could do this with some manual tinkering with the awesome config. However, of course only awesome would then treat things as two separate screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: June 2019. A new feature currently under review for AwesomeWM v4.4 will add a `:split()` method to the screen API. It does what is done below, but better.

I just answered this question here:
[Let awesome wm use only a part of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573248/let-awesome-wm-use-only-a-part-of-the-screen)

This is the code:

```
local wdh = screen[1].geometry.width/2
local x, y = screen[1].geometry.x, screen[1].geometry.y
screen[1]:fake_resize(x, y, wdh, screen[1].geometry.height)
screen.fake_add(x+wdh+1, y, wdh, screen[1].geometry.height)
```

I will add this to the [documentation](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/screen.html) soon.